# JQuery Hide Div when Option is Selected

Tags: jquery, class, html-select, hide

I want to hide a class of a DIV when a specific OPTION Value is selected

```
    <select id="tagtype" name="type">
        <option value="type_s">Standard</option>
        <option value="type_o">Overstock</option>
        <option value="type_snd">Scratch &amp; Dent</option>
        <option value="type_mult">Multiples</option>
    </select>

<div class="multiples>stuff here</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#tagtype option[value='type_mult']").length)
   $("multiples").css('display','none');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the "Multiples" Option?

Comment: I hate that you have to wait to accept an answer, so sometimes I forget about it, thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to do this would probably be something like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#tagtype").change(function() {
      if(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val() == "type_mult") {
         jQuery(".multiples").hide();
      }
   });
});
```

You're binding a handler to the `onChange` event of the select box. Whenever, you select a new option in the select box, the handler is called.

In the handler, `this` refers to the select box that fired the `onChange` event. You look for the value of the selected option. If this value is equal to "type_mult", you hide all elements with the class `multiples`.

The problem with your existing code is that it will only run once; when the page first finishes loading. You need to respond to changes in the select box, which is why you need to bind to the `onChange` event. Another problem is the `if` statement. Even if you used your code and in an `onChange` handler, it enter the `if` block every type because you are not checking to see if the option with the "type_mult" value is selected. You're simply checking to see if it exists. Since it *always* exists, the code inside the `if` will always run. Also, when you want to use class names, you need to put a period in front of the class name. So you want to do `$(.multiples)` and not just `$(multiples)` (the latter will search for a tag named `multiples`, which is not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Needs a bit more info - what actually happens when you run this code?

My guess would be that the second jQuery selector is wrong:

```
$(".multiples").css('display','none');
```

Comment: Nothing happens, i select the 'multiples' option and nothing happens.  I have used the code you mentioned and it does indeed work correctly when the code previous is correct.